# how slice by hybrid stile

Tags: python, dataframe, slice

having a random df

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,10],[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17]], columns=['A', 'B','C','D'])
cols_in = list(df)[0:2]+list(df)[4:]
```

now:

```
x = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
   x.append(df.iloc[i,cols_in])
```

obviously in the cycle, x return an error due to col_in assignment in iloc.

How could be possible apply a mixed style slicing of df like in append function ?

Comment: I find the question unclear.  Do you want to slice your dataframe? Or append to the dataframe? Or append to a list with values from the dataframe by slicing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do . Show us the original problem you are trying to solve and show us your expected result (https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Thanks. I want to append to x slices of df[cols_in] , row by row counted by i

Comment: ..."Or append to a list with values from the dataframe by slicing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to exclude one column? There is no column 4, so depending on which columns you are after, something like this might be what you are after:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,10],[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17]], columns=['A', 'B','C','D'])
```

If you want to get the column indeces from column names you can do:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'D']
cols_in = np.nonzero(df.columns.isin(cols))[0]


x = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
   x.append(df.iloc[i, cols_in].to_list()) 
x
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 7], [7, 8, 10], [10, 11, 13], [14, 15, 17]]
```

Comment: you right, in this example, I want exclude raw #4, but this is not the main point. How can i transform my array of list (cols_in == ['A','B','D']) in array of index (cols_in == [1,2,4]), corresponding to such lists ?

Comment: I've added how to get column indeces from column names

Comment: yes, SORRY, I'm sleeping !!!